# Validate deployment failed deny policy in SQL managed instance Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to create a manged instance within an existing subnet in Azure. I have configured the subnet with the [script provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-configure-vnet-subnet) which tells me the subnet is prepared.

When I create the managed instance I get

> 'Deployment validation failed.
>   Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: The
>   template deployment failed because of policy violation. Please see
>   details for more information.'

If I check the activity log I see

> 'InvalidTemplateDeployment' and 'Operation name 'deny' Policy action'
>   with some further infiormation under the JSON tab e.g.  '
>   eventTimestamp": "2019-10-30T10:22:16.9421982Z",
>       "id": "/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/xx-sqlmi/events/23572bf7-dbbb-4ba0-a13e-075a8ae58652/ticks/637080277369421982",
>       "level": "Error",
>       "operationId": "a12adf73-dd1b-4216-80df-dea57d514ba1",
>       "operationName": {
>           "value": "Microsoft.Authorization/policies/deny/action",
>           "localizedValue": "'deny' Policy action." '

None of this seems to me very helpful, how do i diagnose and fix this error? Is it that my network/subnet configuration is wrong? Permissions? A policy which needs to specify managed instances can be created?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue. One question are you getting this error immediately after running the deployment or after sometime ? For me it worked just fine this is just creating route table

Comment: It happens seconds after pressing create which makes me think it is a permissions issue? A policy forbidding the creation? I did not set up this virtual network and / or resource group, I only set up the subnet for the managed instance to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution:

Go to the resource group you want to create the managed instance in > Policies > Assignments > Allowed resource types (with the scope subscription/resourcegroupname)   parameters > then from the allowed resource types dropdown select Microsoft.Sql.managedInstances

Sign out and into your account, then managed instance will deploy.

When I got the 'Validate Deployment - 'deny' Policy action' error I went to the Activity log, clicked the Validate Deployment error dropown, clicked the 'deny' Policy action, then looked at the JSON tab - if I looked sequntially to see where the error originated I found this section

```
"category": {
    "value": "Policy",
    "localizedValue": "Policy"
},
"eventTimestamp": "2019-10-30T13:04:54.8516173Z",
"id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/minamehere/events/77999a0f-d551-45e0-9b3b-1156b246b50d/ticks/637080374948516173",
```

"resourceId": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/minamehere",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"

Which is what led me to policies and allowed me to troubleshoot and fix the issue - somewhere I knew I needed to add 'Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances' to the Policy category, which fits with the deny policy error I was experiencing.